# Получаются разные хеши SHA256

Tags: c#, c, winapi, хеширование

Получаются разные хеши на C и на C#.

На C:

```
UINT16 data1 = 88;
ULONG  data2 = 74;

PBYTE hash;
DWORD len = 0, sz;

HCRYPTPROV hProv;
HCRYPTHASH hHash;

CryptAcquireContextA(
              reinterpret_cast<HCRYPTPROV*>(&hProv),
              NULL,
              (LPSTR)MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV,
              PROV_RSA_AES,
              CRYPT_NEWKEYSET
          );
CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_SHA_256, 0, 0, &hHash);
CryptHashData(hHash, (PBYTE)&data1, sizeof(UINT16), 0);
CryptHashData(hHash, (PBYTE)&data2, sizeof(ULONG), 0);
CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHSIZE, (BYTE*)&len, &sz, 0);
hash = static_cast<PBYTE>(calloc(1, (size_t)len));
CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHVAL, hash, &len, 0);
```

(проверки убрал для краткости)

На C#:

```
ushort data1 = 88;
UInt32 data2 = 74;
int sz = 0;
byte[] data = new byte[sizeof(UInt32) + sizeof(ushort)];
byte[] hash;
Array.Copy(
      BitConverter.GetBytes(data1), 0, data, sz, sizeof(ushort)); sz += sizeof(ushort);
Array.Copy(
      BitConverter.GetBytes(data2), 0, data, sz, sizeof(UInt32));

using (SHA256Managed hs = new SHA256Managed())
{
    hash = hs.ComputeHash(data);
}
```

Проблемы на первый взгляд не видно, но результат разный.

**Upd:**

Вопрос решен, как всегда невнимательность :)

```
DWORD len = 0, sz = sizeof(DWORD);
```

C: `3a b1 88 5e eb 0b bf f4 cc 42 12 9c 21 09 25 73 64 45 db 52 55 9d 3a 23 40 be 15 2c 70 4b aa 2d`

C#: `3A B1 88 5E EB 0B BF F4 CC 42 12 9C 21 09 25 73 64 45 DB 52 55 9D 3A 23 40 BE 15 2C 70 4B AA 2D`

Comment: Проблема точно не в коде, который вы привели. В меня все ок.

Comment: Вы сравнивали результат выполнения C vs C# ? Хеш одинаковый ?

Comment: Где остальной код? Где начало в первом варианте? Где получение финального хэша в первом варианте?

Comment: C part? там все стандартно, но могу добавить, там не мало получиться с учётом инициализации CryptHash*

Comment: обновил С часть

Comment: @NewView: Что это за чушь? `CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_SHA_256, 0, 0, hHash);` - это как это? Как такой вызов может инициализировать переменную `hHash`, передаваемую *по значению*??? Почему `hHash` вдруг имеет тип `HCRYPTPROV`??? "там все стандартно" говорите? Это где вы видели такое "стандартно"?

Comment: Поправил, брал из функции, туда приходит двойной указатель. Copy&Paste дает о себе знать :)

Comment: И по сути HCRYPTPROV, HCRYPTHASH это одно и тоже - ULONG_PTR

Comment: Да, у меня хеши совпадают, даже с вашим новым кодом. Я только передаю другие параметры в `CryptAcquireContextA`, потому что с вашими она возвращает ошибку: `CryptAcquireContextA(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)`

Comment: Там надо иногда 2 раза вызывать CryptAcquireContextA, если контейнера нет, он его создаёт первым вызовом, а вторым инициализирует. Как то так это работает. Спасибо за тест @Zergatul